# Combine same json values and make it a key using php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following JSON

```
[
   {
      "Date" : "10/7/2014",
      "Data1" : 23
   },
   {
      "Date" : "10/7/2014",
      "Data1" : 23
   },
   {
      "Date" : "10/8/2014",
      "Data1" : 40
   },
    {
      "Date" : "10/8/2014",
      "Data1" : 23
   },
   {
      "Date" : "10/9/2014",
      "Data1" : 55
   },
   {
      "Date" : "10/9/2014",
      "Data1" : 22
   },
]
```

I want to convert same dates to be an array key with different data's to be an each item something like below

```
[
  "10/7/2014" : [{
      "Data1" : 23
   },{
      "Data1" : 23
   }],
  "10/8/2014" : [{
      "Data1" : 40
   },{
      "Data1" : 23
   }],
  "10/9/2014" : [{
      "Data1" : 55
   },{
      "Data1" : 22
   }],
]
```

Is this possible to do using php or javascript?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, you just need to do it. Read your data. Write it to a new array in the desired structure. What part is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through your data and act accordingly. Also, you better change the property name 'Date', because it is a function defined on global scope.

```
var data = [
   {
      "date" : "10/7/2014",
      "Data1" : 23
   },
   {
      "date" : "10/7/2014",
      "Data1" : 23
   },
   {
      "date" : "10/8/2014",
      "Data1" : 40
   },
    {
      "date" : "10/8/2014",
      "Data1" : 23
   },
   {
      "date" : "10/9/2014",
      "Data1" : 55
   },
   {
      "date" : "10/9/2014",
      "Data1" : 22
   },
]

var results = {}

data.forEach(function(obj){
  if (obj['date'] in results){
     results[obj['date']].push({Data1 : obj['Data1']});
  }else{
     results[obj['date']] = [{Data1 : obj['Data1']}];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode($json)`

The example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
json_decode($json)
```

Would return

```
array(5) {
 ["a"] => int(1)
 ["b"] => int(2)
 ["c"] => int(3)
 ["d"] => int(4)
 ["e"] => int(5)
}
```